# (Telegram bot/Pyrogram) How to make a text randomizer on Python that will be picking random text without a need to restart the code?

Tags: python, random, telegram, telegram-bot

I wanted to make a telegram bot which sends you a random word from text file (need that for a project) I made this:

```
import random
lines = open('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\singnplur.txt').read().splitlines()
myline =random.choice(lines)

@bot.on_message(filters.command('rng') & filters.private)
def command1(bot, message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, myline)
```

And it works, but the word is being randomized only once and you need to restart the bot to pick another. What should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python interprets top to bottom, line per line.

Since you're storing `myline` first, and then call your `command1` function repeatedly later, you'll keep using the same content from `myline`.
If you want to get a new word every time, store your list of words, and only choose a random item with `command1`:

```py
with open("words.txt") as f:  # automatically closes file afterwards
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

@bot.on_message(...)
def command(bot, message):
    word = random.choice(lines)  # Choose random item every time
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, word)
```